# Screen managment XNA C#

Tags: c#, xna

I'm trying to implement screen management into my XNA game.

So far I've successfully implemented Example 3 from this link: http://www.xnadevelopment.com/tutorials/thestateofthings/thestateofthings.shtml

My current screen switch event is as follows:

```
    public void GoToScreenOverview(object obj, EventArgs e)
    {
        screenStart = null;
        screenOverview = new ScreenOverview(this, new EventHandler(GoToScreenOverview), globalVariables);
        mCurrentScreen = screenOverview;            
    }
```

This moves from the (initial) screen "Start", and moves the game to the next screen "Overview". The equivalent reciprocal method GoToScreenStart does the opposite.

My question is this: How do I manage all the events?

Let's say I have 20 screens. Each screen Class will need 19 EventHandlers passed to it, which seems massively inefficient, and makes it a pain to add a new screen. Currently GoToScreenX type are events are in the Game1 class, but it seems to me that it would make more sense for all the events to be in the "BaseScreen" class, which each Screen inherits from.

Answer (score 6):

If I were you, I would create a `ScreenManager` class. You could start with something like this:

```
public class ScreenManager
{
    List<GameScreen> screens;
    bool isinitialized = false;

    public override void Initialize()
    {
        base.Initialize();
        isinitialized = true;
    }

    protected override void LoadContent()
    {
         foreach (GameScreen screen in screens)
             screen.LoadContent();
    }

    public void AddScreen(GameScreen screen)
    {
        screens.Add(screen);
        if (isinitialized) screen.LoadContent();
    }

    // also create a removescreen

    public void Draw(Gametime gametime)
    {
        foreach (GameScreen screen in screens)
        {
            screen.Draw(gametime);
        }
    }
    // also create a similar method for Updating
}
```

You could make ScreenManager a `DrawableGameComponent` (recommended), or you could have the maingame call `ScreenManager.Update()` and `ScreenManager.Draw()` in it's respective methods. Finally, you'd have to create an abstract `GameScreen` class that has update and draw methods, and then have all your other Game Screens inherit from the `GameScreen` class. hopefully this will give you some ideas.